# How do I access elements in a 2D array?

Tags: actionscript-3

So I'm working on a `2D array` program to keep track of student info in a seperate .as3 file as follows

```
eleve[0] = ["Charles","Westmoreland",78,81,96,76];
```

I currently have eleve (student) ranging from 0 to 14. None of the buttons I have programmed so far work and the computer teacher at my school isn't familiar with as3 so he tried to help but couldn't.
The code is [here](http://pastebin.com/suUecQAY) (all the code is there so I didn't want to put it in here).
Any help for fixing the buttons would be highly appreciated.
EDIT : Sorry about the french comments, I'm in a french school. And by the buttons don't work I meant clicking them does nothing. No errors or anything else either. I also updated the code.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking.  Your code comments are all in french which makes it that more difficult.    Be more specific when you say "don't work".   Do you see your buttons?  When you click them does nothing happen?   How are your button instantiated - via dropped on your U2A4 timeline?

Comment: your student should be an object, not an array

Answer (score 3):

When accessing a 2D array you want to do this:
`var info = myArray[i][j];`

NOT this:
`var info = myArray[i,j]`

So to print the name of the first student (index 0) do this:
`trace(eleve[0][0] + " " + eleve[0][1]);`

Check out this page in the Adobe docs: [Multidimensional arrays](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee9.html).